# Finding the cell to the right of the index match

Tags: excel

```
      D          E         F
8   1089.80    35.87    1079.82
9   1079.81    35.95
10  1079.84    35.78
```

Currently I am finding the value in Column D that is closest to the value in cell F8 (1079.82).

```
=INDEX(D8:D10,MATCH(MIN(ABS(D8:D10-F8)),ABS(D8:D10-F8),0))
```

This formula is correct and returns 1079.81, but I am looking to return the value to the right of 1079.81 which is 35.95.

Any tips on how to return the value in the cell to the right of the index match? I know you can add +1 but this just returns the value in the column below the index match.

Comment: Change the `D8:D10` to `E8:E10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the array to look in and add column number '2':

`=INDEX(D8:E10,MATCH(MIN(ABS(D8:D10-F8)),ABS(D8:D10-F8),0),2)`

Comment: In my opinion this is overcomplicating - just change to `E8:E10`.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an over complication, but your solution should work as well. Thanks